# Read and Write to a specific cell in a file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am writing a program where it reads from an excel sheet, it randomly picks a row (100 rows, 2 columns).

```
with open("file1.csv") as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
     for index, row in enumerate(reader):
         if index == 0:
            chosen_row = row
         else:
            r = random.randint(0, index)
            if r == 0:
                chosen_row = row
```

I want it to write to a specific row/column. 
For example; if it randomly picks from row 4, column A. It would write the answer to row4, column B.

Here is what I have (it's wrong and it doesn't write to the specific cell)

```
    x = input(chosen_row[0])
    srcfile = openpyxl.load_workbook("file1.csv",read_only=False, 
    keep_vba= True)
    sheetname = srcfile.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    sheetname.cell(row=chosen_index,column=2).value = x 
    srcfile.save('file1.csv')
```

I want to know how it can randomly pick a row, and have my code get the user's input and write it to the specific cell of the that row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the example code on openpyxl:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()

# grab the active worksheet
ws = wb.active

# Data can be assigned directly to cells
ws['A1'] = 42
```

Given this, you should be able to see assigned the value of a given cell with

```
ws['A1']
```

and assign random other with:

```
ws['A1']=ws[random[row]+random[cell]]
```

ramdom[row/cell] is psudocode. You'd select how you want to define the random[row/cell] data.

Don't forget to save, btw.

```
# Save the file
wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```